# How to use polymorphism for variables

Tags: variables, go, polymorphism

I am new in Go and started learning about polymorphism.
I know how to do it when multiple objects need to use the same function.
But I have a new problem, I don't know what to do in a case I have the same variable on different objects.

In the following example I have two different objects: `struct1` and `struct2`. Both of them have the same variable `name`.
I can run over them and check which is which and work accordingly (you can test it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/vX9BYTLGl2c)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type struct1 struct {
    name string
}

type struct2 struct {
    name string
}

func main(){
    structMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    s1 := struct1{name:"struct1_name"}
    s2 := struct2{name:"struct2_name"}
    structMap["struct1"] = s1
    structMap["struct2"] = s2

    for key, _ := range structMap {
        switch key {
            case "struct1":
                generic := structMap[key].(struct1)
                fmt.Println(generic.name)
            case "struct2":
                generic := structMap[key].(struct2)
                fmt.Println(generic.name)
        }
    }
}
```

But if I had 20 objects ? I would need to do 20 checks?
So I wonder if it possible to do an interface with variables, something like:

```
type genericStruct interfcae {
   name string
}

...
for key, _ := range structMap {
    generic := structMap[key].(genericStruct)
    fmt.Println(generic.name)

}
```

Of course this code doesn't work because I don't know how to do it, but I wanted to know about a way to do it.

**EDIT:**
I tried to use interface based on the example from:
https://gobyexample.com/interfaces
Thanks for Robbie Milejczak and the other guys who help me.

This the new working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type struct1 struct {
    name string
}

type struct2 struct {
    name string
}

type genericInterface interface {
    GetName() string
}

func (r struct1 ) GetName() string{
    return r.name
}

func (r struct2 ) GetName() string{
    return r.name
}

func printName(g interface{}){
    a := g.(genericInterface)
    fmt.Println(a.GetName())
}

func main(){
    structMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    s1 := struct1{name:"struct1_name"}
    s2 := struct2{name:"struct2_name"}
    structMap["struct1"] = s1
    structMap["struct2"] = s2

    for key, _ := range structMap {
    printName(structMap[key])
    }
}
```

Comment: *"So I wonder if it possible to do an interface with variables, something like:"* No, it isn't.

Comment: This is weird, this is pretty advanced language. They don't have solution for such basic problem :/

Comment: This is not duplication, I understand that it is not possible to use variables inside interfaces. I am asking if there other solution for polymorphism problem when it comes to variables

Comment: If you have multiple types that share a common structure, then the way to do it would be *composition*, I believe. You can then have the "containers" implement a one method interface that provides access to this common structure.

Comment: Add `getName` method to all types (example: `func (v struct1) getName() string  { return v.name }`, define interface `type getNamer interface { getName() string }`, use that type as the value type for the `structMap`.

Comment: @E235 https://play.golang.com/p/Bs0gfOPNHtu

Comment: @E235 "I am asking if there other solution for polymorphism" - no. Interfaces are the only form of polymorphism in Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this contrived example you could use getters / setters instead of static properties to leverage interfaces:

```
type GenericStruct interface {
   GetName() string
}
```

And now any struct with a receiver called `GetName` will satisfy the `GenericStruct` interface:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  Name string
}

func (ms *MyStruct) GetName() string {
  return ms.Name
}
```

This could get messy with more complex structs, in which case you may want to consider the composition suggestion (typically achieved via [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)) or a third party library such as [genny](https://github.com/cheekybits/genny)

Comment: So I will need to add `MyStruct` as a field in my objects to make it work?

Comment: no, for this example you just need to set the expected type to the interface. If the function accepts a `GenericStruct` then *any* struct with a receiver called `GetName` will satisfy it. Go uses this pattern heavily, for example any thing that satisfies the `io.Writer` interface can be used as an argument to `fmt.Fprintf`, which includes `strings.Builder`, `os.File` etc. I merely included reference to more complex constructs for further consideration, sorry if that was confusing

Comment: I added the following interface + 2 functions for each struct: `type GenericStruct interface {
   GetName() string
}

func (gs *struct2) GetName() string {
  return gs.name
}

func (gs *struct1) GetName() string {
  return gs.name
}`  in the `main` function I added ` g := structMap[key].(GenericStruct)
 fmt.Print(g)` but now I am receiving different error: `interface conversion: main.struct1 is not main.GenericStruct: missing method GetName`. This is because the method `GetName` is not related to `struct1`.

Comment: I think I must add new field to the my objects `struct1` and `struct2` but this means that I won't be able to do it when working with objects from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: you're doing it wrong, you don't need any sort of assertion for this to work https://gobyexample.com/interfaces see how both circle and rect structs are instances of the geometry interface implicitly, because they have all the required method definitions

Comment: OK, now it is more clear. I edited my answer based on what you wrote, now the new problem is because the array of the object is a key,value while the value is `interface{}` so the new function `printName` can't get `interface{}` inside it. I need to find a way to convert the `interface{}` to `genericInterface`

Comment: Oh ! I succeed, cool ! I edited the answer